# How to select columns from one table where id in JSON column of other table

Tags: mysql, json

I have two tables `topics` and `assessments` the `topics` table is a basic table with `id` and `name` and in `assessment` table there is a JSON column called `topic_list` where array of topics is stored. I need the list of topics for a specific assessment with `id` and `name`.

```
CREATE TABLE `topics` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'topic name will capture here',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=0 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE `assessments` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `topic_list` json DEFAULT NULL,
  `assessment_name` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=0 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

INSERT INTO `topics` (name) values
  ('topic1'),
  ('topic2'),
  ('topic3');

INSERT INTO `assessments` (topic_list, assessment_name) values
  ('[1,2]','assessment1'),
  ('[2,3]', 'assessment2'),
  ('[1,3]', 'assessment3');

SELECT t1.id,t1.name FROM topics AS t1 
WHERE id IN (SELECT topic_list FROM assessments WHERE id = 1)
```

This is what I have tried but just getting first row:

```
SELECT id,name from topics where id in(select JSON_UNQUOTE(TRIM(TRAILING ']' FROM TRIM(LEADING '[' FROM JSON_EXTRACT(topic_list, '$[*]')))) from assessments where id = 1)
```

What I got is:

```
1   topic1
```

Results just first column from the array.

I was trying for:

```
1   topic1
2   topic2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use one of the following solutions using [`JSON_EXTRACT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-extract) and [`JSON_CONTAINS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-contains):

```
SELECT id, name 
FROM topics WHERE (
  SELECT JSON_CONTAINS(
    JSON_EXTRACT(topic_list, '$[*]'), 
    CONVERT(topics.id, JSON)
  ) FROM assessments WHERE id = 1
);
```

... or (with `INNER JOIN`):

```
SELECT topics.id, topics.name 
FROM topics INNER JOIN assessments 
  ON JSON_CONTAINS(JSON_EXTRACT(topic_list, '$[*]'), CONVERT(topics.id, JSON)) = 1
WHERE assessments.id = 1
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f41177f20c49eb70b7d53c909c894f93)

**Note:** A faster solution can be an additional table with the mapping between topics and assessments instead of saving the topics list in the assessment record itself.

Comment: Thanks, this saved my day but a small doubt is this query optimised i mean if i have too many records will this query be fast

Comment: A faster solution can be an additional table with the mapping between topic and assessments instead of saving the topic list in the assessment itself.